# xelatex and nag problem

Tags: xetex, xpatch, nag

Somet time ago `xelatex` stopped to compile my document.

> LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `xpatch`, but the package provides `xparse`.
>
> Package: xparse 2016/03/28 v6468 L3 Experimental document command parser
>   (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
>   ! Missing $ inserted.
>    
>                  $
>   l.12
>
> I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
>   you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
>
> Overfull \hbox (43.7436pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 27--12
>   []\EU1/lmr/m/n/10 Id: xpatch.dtx 0.3 2012-10-02 12:00:00Z Enrico $[]$ 
>   []
>
> Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
>   \etb@tempcnta=\count134
>   )
>   ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
>   \etoolbox.sty-h@@k ->\etoolbox.sty-h@@k 
>                                          \etb@catcodes \undef \etb@catcodes 
>   l.43 \cs_generate_variant:Nn
>                               \tl_if_in:NnT { Nx } 
>   If you really absolutely need more capacity,
>   you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

after deleting line by line I gain following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

It seems like `nag`+`fontspec`+`imakeidx` conflict? If I comment any of those lines (`RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}`, `usepackage{fontspec}` or `usepackage{imakeidx}`) or even `l2tabu` parameter it works.

Comment: A nice and really minimal MWE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `xpatch` is loaded by `imakeidx` at begin document, every sort of evil will happen if `nag` is loaded.

I don't think I'll add patches for supporting `nag` (a package I don't recommend). Note that similar issues can arise whenever a package is loaded at begin document, when `nag` is loaded.

You can work around the issue by explicitly loading `xpatch` before `imakeidx`.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: On one hand, I wonder if I should alter our loader to set the catcode of `$`, but on the other I'm not really a fan of `\GetIdInfo` so ...

Comment: @JosephWright I think I'll remove `\GetIdInfo` in future versions. This should solve this issue, but I still see no point in using `nag`. One doesn't call “duck” a “sheep”, when knowing the correct name; in my opinion, `nag` is just about “don't call sheep a duck”.